# Is there a way to create folders with security in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, security, temporary

I'm trying to create a temporary folder, but this folder has to be unerasable and the files inside it too.

is there a way to do it using c# and WPF?

Comment: Define "unerasable." You mean, the user cannot delete the folder/file from the file system?..

Comment: yes, the user cannot deleter folder/file from system.

Comment: It is not possible in native/managed code if user can get admin permissions. Look into [FileSecutiry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) which will let you setup permissions whatever way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to make a hidden folder using:

```
using System.IO; 

string path = @"c:\newHiddenFolder";
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
{ 
  DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
  di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden; 
}
```

Comment: But with this, I stil can erase the files, is there a way to deny the user to delete them?

Comment: No, if the use has sufficient rights. If the user, for instance has admin rights on the box, she can do whatever she damned well pleases.